# How to search a sub-string in elements of a list speedily?

Tags: python, python-2.7, search

I have some data like this:

```
data = [
    'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
    'CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1810',
    'DATE: Wed, 14 May 2014 12:15:19 GMT',
    'EXT:',
    'LOCATION: http://192.168.94.57:9000/DeviceDescription.xml',
    'SERVER: Windows NT/5.0, UPnP/1.0, pvConnect UPnP SDK/1.0',
    'ST: uuid:7076436f-6e65-1063-8074-78542e239ff5',
    'USN: uuid:7076436f-6e65-1063-8074-78542e239ff5',
    'Content-Length: 0',
    '',
    ''
]
```

from which I have to extract the ".xml" link.

My code is:

```
for element in data:
    if 'LOCATION' in element:
        xmllink = element.split(': ').[1]
```

It's taking too much time - how can I make this more speedy?

Comment: By the way, you should really copy-paste your code rather than re-typing it ... there's a typo in the above that causes a syntax error, so it doesn't run at all (never mind speedily).

Comment: `next(d.partition(':')[-1].strip() for d in data if d.startswith('LOCATION'))` is a very readable and short way to also get at the exact same answer, but it is "much" slower, on the order of 1.5 seconds per *one million* iterations.  The upside is it is robust to `LOCATION:` vs `LOCATION:_` Is speed *actually* an issue?

Answer (score 2):

With the usual caveats that

1. Premature optimization is the root of all evil, and
2. Python is built for comfort, not for speed ...

This ought to be a little faster:

```
for element in data:
    if element.startswith('LOCATION: '):
        xmllink = element[10:]  # len('LOCATION: ') == 10
        break
```

... but, like your code, it'll break if there isn't exactly one space after `LOCATION:`, and in many other situations that may or may not occur with your data.